# How to make RequireJS-compatible library to be includable to other JS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I develop an application and some modules for it.
This modules I include with RequireJS, but want to include also in another applications which has not RequireJS support.

How need I to modify my library file to let it to be included in other JS file (by copying content)?

So I want library to have both ways of use:

```
requirejs(["helper/util"], function(util) {
  // library loaded
  window.MyUtilModule = util;
  window.MyUtilModule.someFunc();
});
```

and

```
/* >> No RequreJS library load here << */
/* >> Code copied from 'helper/util.js' goes here << */
window.MyUtilModule.someFunc(); // already loaded by simple including code into another file
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about UMD. Typical UMD header looks like:

```
(function (factory) {
  if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    module.exports = factory(require('backbone'), require('underscore'));
  } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(['backbone', 'underscore'], factory);
  }
}(function (Backbone, _) {
  // your code
}));
```